# CsvHelper custom delimiter

Tags: csvhelper

In earlier versions of CsvHelper, I could set the default delimiter like this:

```
using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
csv.Configuration.Delimiter = "~";
```

How do I do this same thing in the current version (version 22)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After a bit of Googling, I found [this post](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/27#issuecomment-773222383) in the CsvHelper issues. So, in the context of my original question, the correct code is now:

```cs
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) { Delimiter = "~" };
using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config);
```

Comment: Nice. I'm hoping this means that Delimiter = "\t" can be used for tab delimited files