# Header with name [0] not found

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have this csv file i need to be able to read and I cant get it to work. here is the [csv](https://pastebin.com/pLVh10wa) and a [picture of csv](https://imgshare.io/image/csv.pWvQrq). Im not sure what the problem is, I have been following the tutorials so I have a guess that it might be something with the csv file and the spacing it is using. I cannot change anything in the csv.
I have tried adding Name properties to the class and also index properties.

CsvHelper version: 27.1.0

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\C#\price_detail.csv"))
        {
            using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                var records = csvReader.GetRecords<SKU>();
            }
        }
    }




public class SKU
{
    //[Name("PriceValueId")]
    public string PriceValueId { get; set; }

    //[Name("Created")]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    //[Name("Modified")]
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }

    //[Name("CatalogEntryCode")]
    public string CatalogEntryCode { get; set; }

    //[Name("MarketId")]
    public string MarketId { get; set; }

    //[Name("CurrencyCode")]
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }

    //[Name("ValidFrom")]
    public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }

    //[Name("ValidUntil")]
    public DateTime ValidUntil { get; set; }

    //[Name("UnitPrice")]
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

}
```

**Debug output:**

```
Header with name 'PriceValueId'[0] was not found.

Header with name 'Created'[0] was not found.

Header with name 'Modified'[0] was not found.

Header with name 'CatalogEntryCode'[0] was not found.

Header with name 'MarketId'[0] was not found.

Header with name 'CurrencyCode'[0] was not found.

Header with name 'ValidFrom'[0] was not found.

Header with name 'ValidUntil'[0] was not found.

Header with name 'UnitPrice'[0] was not found.

If you are expecting some headers to be missing and want to ignore this validation, set the configuration HeaderValidated to null. You can also change the functionality to do something else, like logging the issue.

IReader state:

   ColumnCount: 0

   CurrentIndex: -1

   HeaderRecord:

["PriceValueId  Created Modified    CatalogEntryCode    MarketId    CurrencyCode    ValidFrom   ValidUntil  UnitPrice"]

IParser state:

   ByteCount: 0

   CharCount: 101

   Row: 1

   RawRow: 1

   Count: 1

   RawRecord:

PriceValueId    Created Modified    CatalogEntryCode    MarketId    CurrencyCode    ValidFrom   ValidUntil  UnitPrice
```

Comment: Looks like your CSV is TAB-separated. You can specify another delimiter like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60474975/csvhelper-does-not-parse-my-tab-delimited-csv-file

Comment: It seems the csvReader.Configuration.Delimiter is read only now and cant be changed that way

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66166584/csvhelper-custom-delimiter/66166656#66166656

Comment: Thank you! That last link worked. No I just need to figure out how to handle DateTime when it's Null.

Answer (score 6):

CsvReader accepts `comma` as default delimiter, so if your file has a different delimiter like `semicolon`, you need to define CsvReader like this.

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(FILE_PATH))
using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) { Delimiter = ";", Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 }))
{
    var records = csvReader.GetRecords<SKU>().ToList();                  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you already figured out you need to change the delimiter to be a tab. You also need to make sure the property `ValidUntil` is nullable and then add "NULL" as a `NullValue` to the `TypeConverterOptionsCache`

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        Delimiter = "\t"
    };

    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\C#\price_detail.csv"))
    using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, config))
    {
        csvReader.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<DateTime?>().NullValues.Add("NULL");
        
        var records = csvReader.GetRecords<SKU>();
    }   
}

public class SKU
{
    public string PriceValueId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    public string CatalogEntryCode { get; set; }
    public string MarketId { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ValidUntil { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I add **csvReader.ReadHeader()** and it works.

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(CSV_FILE_PATH))
{
    using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csvReader.Read();
        csvReader.ReadHeader();
        var records = csvReader.GetRecords<SKU>();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my csv was a very regular, comma-separated file. I then compared it in Notepad++ against another csv that reads fine. The problem was that the bad file has its encoding in Unix style, while the good one had it in Windows style.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the csv fileformat was **'UTF8 with BOM'**

I had to save it as 'UTF8' and the Error 'Header with name [0] not found' doaes not raise again.